# Correct return codes for REST stores

Tags: http, rest, protocols, http-method

I am trying to figure out the right response for a REST store. I am well aware of the relevant RFC 2616; the relevant part is [9 Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6)

Now...

The short question:

If I create a resource using POST or PUT, and do NOT want to return the current resource data, what code shall I use? Is 204 OK? ( I doubt it)

I have outlined how I implemented these methods in [JsonRestStore](https://github.com/mercmobily/JsonRestStores) here: https://github.com/mercmobily/JsonRestStores/blob/master/jsonrest.md

OK, here is the longer version.

Starting points:

- PUT  either CREATES or OVERWRITES a resource (depending on whether the resource already existed)
- POST either CREATES or MODIFIES a resource (depending on the ID being passed [to "append to it", that is "POST passing specific ID"], or not passed [to create])
- The store MIGHT RETURN the resource as it's on the server, or return NO content

This is how stores are often used. Yes, you CAN pass the resource ID to a POST -- it may sound strange, but it's done to do so.

## Question 1: the case of PUTting a NEW resource without returning contents

The RFC says:

> If a new resource is created, the origin server MUST inform the user agent via the 201 (Created) response. If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful completion of the request.

- CASE 1: Existing resource being modified by PUT:

  - 200 (OK) if you want to return the current resource
  - 204 (No content) if you want to say "OK" and not return anything.
- CASE 2: New resource being created

  - 201 (Created) if you want to return the current resource
  - ??? If you don't want to return anything

So, what about if you CREATED a new resource, but do NOT want to return its current status to the server? Is it OK to return 201 with EMPTY content? Isn't that something for 204? But then I cannot do that, since (according to the RFC) I *must* return 201.

## Question 2: the case of POSTting a NEW resource,  without returning contents

About POSTing, the RFC has to say:

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.
>
> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location header (see section 14.30).

If I accept that the second part doesn't actually apply to REST stores, because a POST will always result in a resource that is reachable somehow, I end up with:

- CASE 1: Existing resource being "appended to", AKA "POST with ID" (resource NOT created)

  - ??? if you want to return the current resource
  - ??? if you don't want to return the current resource
- CASE 2: New resource being created (commonly by NOT passing the ID)

  - 201 (Created) if you want to return the current resource
  - ??? If you do NOT want to return the current resource

However, if I decide to interpret the RFC "The action performed by the POST method might not result (...)" as "If you do a Post append", which is a huuuuge stretch, then I end up with:

- CASE 1: Existing resource being "appended to", AKA "POST with ID" (resource NOT created)

  - 200 (OK)  if you want to return the current resource
  - 204 (No content) if you don't want to return the current resource
- CASE 2: New resource being created (commonly by NOT passing the ID)

  - 201 (Created) if you want to return the current resource
  - ??? If you do NOT want to return the current resource

So, even with interpreting the RFC as *broadly* as possible, I still end up with the question: if I create the resource, and do NOT want to return the current resource data, what code shall I use? Is 204 OK? ( I doubt it)

Bye,

Merc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd always return a 201 where you're told that you must return one.

Note from your own quote:

> and contain an entity which describes the status of the request

Note that it's *not* saying that you have to include the *resource* as content. Just an entity that describes the status. But if there's only one possible status, I see no issue with having no content.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the HTTP/1.1 revision (work in progress), in particular http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22.html#header.content-location.